# how to make a function based on taking the mean faster

Tags: r

I have a data

```
    df <- structure(list(A = c(482590, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 484830, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1127300), B = c(265440, 0, 0, 305820, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 279470, 0, 394370, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 902040), 
    C = c(368610L, 0L, 0L, 366220L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 507830L, 
    0L, 616740L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 799360L), D = c(1088200, 
    0, 0, 720090, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 272930, 0, 1136300, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 805500), E = c(863720L, 0L, 0L, 545860L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 381660L, 0L, 1952700L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 639660L), F = c(715590L, 0L, 0L, 1060200L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 120540L, 0L, 977980L, 0L, 2018900L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 630630L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"
), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to get an output like this

```
df2<- structure(c(374015, 0, 372213.333333333, 0, 317025, 0), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2"), NULL))
```

I can do it by the following code but I am wondering if there is a faster way and cleaner way to do it?

```
func <- function(x) { x=as.numeric(x)
  y = mean(mean(x, na.rm=T), x[2], na.rm=T)
  return(y)
}

df2 <- t(rollapply(t(cbind(NA,df,NA)),width=3,FUN=func,by.column=T))
```

Comment: It seems you could compute the cumulative sum at front and manipulate matrix subsetting like `n = 3; cs = do.call(cbind, Reduce("+", df, accumulate = TRUE)); (cs[, n:ncol(cs)] - cbind(0, cs[, 1:n])) / n`. To make it complete, you could try playing more with indexing `cs` or call a `rowMeans` on the first/last `n - 1` columns

Comment: @G. Grothendieck sure thing that the df2 is a matrix but cannot we have NAs inside a matrix ? can you give me a solution ?

Comment: @G. Grothendieck sorry I could not understand you said `Yes, but you don't in the example`

Comment: @G. Grothendieck I pasted a bigger example above, but if you still need bigger I can update it. I checked the data by `any(is.na(mydata))`and it was `[1] TRUE`  but the data is huge so I don't know where they are to put it in there but probably we can simulate an example, no?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question,

- `mean(x, y)` is not the mean of `x` and `y`.  It means the mean of `x` with a `trim` value of `y`.  See `?mean` `
- `df2` in the question is a matrix, not a data.frame, contrary to what is implied by its name.
- there are no NAs in the input data. The only NAs are the ones you added yourself by using the `cbind(NA, x, NA)` construct.  Thus we can avoid considering NAs by just not using that construct and this also allows us to avoid defining `func`

Try this code:

```
library(zoo)

tm_in <- t(df)
m_out <- t((rollapply(tm_in, 3, mean, partial = TRUE) + tm_in)/2)
```

If you are willing to allow the two endpoints to be NA or to fix them up afterwards then this would be even faster:

```
m_out <- t((rollmean(tm_in, 3, fill = NA) + tm_in)/2)
```

Also if you store the input and output as transposed matrices from the start then the transposing and conversion from data frame can be saved.

Another thing  you could try would be `roll_sum` in RcppRoll which uses C++ and is likely faster.